# Processing JSON into class

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to process a json that I will get from an httprequest into a class. But the problem is that he will keep to crash when I try to save data into my class

```
Boolean hasmore = tree.get("has_more").getBooleanValue();
    if (hasmore == true) {
        System.out.println("Ik geraak hier");
        JsonNode resourceArrayNode=tree.get("photos");
        for(JsonNode jsonNode:resourceArrayNode){
            int height=jsonNode.get("height").getIntValue();
            result[i].setHeight(height);
            //System.out.println(result[i].getHeight());
            i++;
        }
```

so this is the code that will process the height of a picture. the problem is that he will crash when I set this to my class with a javaexceptionpointer and I find it quiet weird because everything has been set right

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.hp.gisware.panoramio.PanoramioResponseDeserializer.deserialize(PanoramioResponseDeserializer.java:29)
    at com.hp.gisware.panoramio.PanoramioResponseDeserializer.deserialize(PanoramioResponseDeserializer.java:15)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:768)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:460)
    at com.hp.gisware.panoramio.GenericJsonPanoramioGeocoder.transmitLocation(GenericJsonPanoramioGeocoder.java:33)
    at com.hp.gisware.panoramio.PanoramioRunner.main(PanoramioRunner.java:26)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58050', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: Have you tried Google's Gson API? That's very easy to use to convert JSON response into Java classes...

Comment: Copy/paste the exact exception message into your question.  (And learn how to interpret the exception info.)

Comment: This is not quite an answer, but a recommendation; JSON Simple library. It's super light-weight and has all the essentials. See: http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

Comment: It's not the JSON that is making the fault because I tested it without the class and it will give the height back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are getting a null pointer exception when writing to result array.
Has it been properly initialized?  It does seem like a bad choice to write this JSON array (could be any length) into a java array (declared with a fixed length).  Could you use a collection like a list instead?

Either that or get("Height") is returning null.
You should probably check before dereferencing it :

```
if(jsonNode.has("Height")) {
    int height=jsonNode.get("height").getIntValue();
    result[i].setHeight(height);
}
```

Otherwise please include the java exception message in the question.

EDIT : (added stack trace)
Well, that is strange.  The stack trace does not look like it is from your code - at least none of the method names match anything from the code you've posted.  Could this be from another thread instead?  Possibly your code triggers code in another thread to send / receive JSON message?  You could try adding a try-catch block to catch NullPointerException, to veryify it is really being thrown from this block of code

Comment: added the message to my question

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries that could help you with parsing a json object into a Java class. Google's GSON 
https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

and Jackson 
http://jackson.codehaus.org/

You seem to be using Jackson, I think. Please, specify which library and version you use and post the stacktrace so we can help you further. And, also, we seem to be living in the same country: the Netherlands.

Comment: It's not the JSON because if I debug it will get a result into height but it will not pass to the class

Comment: @stevedc give us the stacktrace.

Comment: how is the country significant here? does jackson not work in the rest of the world

Comment: @AtharvaJohri it was, indeed, an offtopic.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved I did'nt declare every object result not as a new object of it's class